# Why are attributes in a class undefined when they have been initialized before?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my code I have a class called WorkspaceDatabase which is derived from the [Dynamic Tree Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mrbdympaoae?file=app%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts).
I already added some debugging info to it to get a better understanding ofthe problem.

**Problem:**

In `complete()` the first weird thing happens:
`this.wsnodes.push` fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, but as far as I can see, I initialized it.

The next thing that happens is that in `getChildren` `console.log(this.workspaces);` returns an array of length 0.
But initialData() runs before it and `this.workspaces` gets the value of `ws` and it is printed to the console correctly `(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`.

Can someone explain what I'm not getting right?

```
export class WorkspaceDatabase {

  workspacesService: WorkspacesService;
  workspaces: RQMWorkspace[] = new Array();
  wsnodes: WorkspaceFlatNode[] = new Array();


  setWorkspaceService(workspaceService: WorkspacesService) {
    this.workspacesService = workspaceService;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.wsnodes.push(new WorkspaceFlatNode(123, "test", true, 0, true));
    console.log("WorkspaceDatabase constructed");
  }

  initialData() {
    this.workspacesService.getWorkspaces().subscribe(
      {
        next(ws) {
          this.workspaces = ws;
          console.log(this.workspaces);
        },
        complete() {
          this.workspaces.forEach((ws) => {
            if (ws.workspace_id == null) {
              console.log(this.wsnodes);
              this.wsnodes.push(new WorkspaceFlatNode(ws.id, ws.name, true, 0, true))
            }
          });
          console.log("completed");
          console.log(this.wsnodes);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getChildren(id: number): WorkspaceFlatNode[] | undefined {
    let children: WorkspaceFlatNode[] = new Array();
    console.log(this.workspaces);
    this.workspaces.forEach((ws) => {
      if (ws.workspaceId == id) {
        ws.workspaces.forEach((innerWs) => {
          children.push(new WorkspaceFlatNode(innerWs.id, innerWs.name, true, 0, true))
        });
        ws.documents.forEach((doc) => {
          children.push(new WorkspaceFlatNode(doc.id, doc.name, false, 0, true))
        });
      }
    })
    return children;
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for `this.workspaces`? The first `console.log(this.workspaces);` in `initialData` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`complete` method uses a function syntax which has a different `this`. Instead of passing functions, you can use arrow function which will retain `this` property of the parent.

```
initialData() {
    this.workspacesService.getWorkspaces().subscribe(
      ws => { //<--- arrow function

          this.workspaces = ws;
          console.log(this.workspaces);
        },
     err => {
        },
     () => { //<--- arrow function
          this.workspaces.forEach((ws) => {
            if (ws.workspace_id == null) {
              console.log(this.wsnodes);
              this.wsnodes.push(new WorkspaceFlatNode(ws.id, ws.name, true, 0, true))
            }
          });
          console.log("completed");
          console.log(this.wsnodes);
        }
    );
  }
```

Assuming that you're calling `getChildren` method before the `this.workspacesService.getWorkspaces()` has completed, `this.workspaces` does not have any data. 
Once the `this.workspacesService.getWorkspaces()` completes, only then the `workspaces` array will be populated.

Comment: The second arrow function in your code will not be called when the observable completes, but when it errors.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `complete()` method, `this` is the current object, i.e. the object passed as argument to `subscribe()`. Not the component.

Use arrow functions.

See [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkry2p](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkry2p) for a demo:

```
// not working
of('hello 1').subscribe({
  next(prefix) {
    console.log(prefix + ' ' + this.name);
  }
});

// working
of('hello 2').subscribe(prefix => console.log(prefix + ' ' + this.name)
);

// also working
of('hello 3').subscribe({
  next: prefix => console.log(prefix + ' ' + this.name)
});
```